# Error While making crud page using a single servlet

Tags: java, forms, servlets, jdbc, oracle10g

I am trying to create a servlet which perform different funtions(create,read,update,delete) on database by comparing the value of submit button from html page and according to that perform the funvtion assigned to that value of submit button.
HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="HelloServlet" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="ID" name="id">
    <input type="text" placeholder="NAME" name="name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="SALARY" name="salary">
    <input type="submit" value="add" name="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="view" name="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="update" name="submit">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

JavaFile(Servlet):

```
package com.gaurav;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.jasper.tagplugins.jstl.core.Out;
@WebServlet("/HelloServlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
    private String user="system";
    private String pass="inception";
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // Set response content type


        // Actual logic goes here.

        //String name=request.getParameter("name");
        //out.println(name);

    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        String name=request.getParameter("name");
        int salary=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("salary"));
        try{

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            out.println("class not found ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(request.getParameter("submit").equals("add")){ 
        try{

            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
            //Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","inception");
            String query="INSERT INTO employee VALUES(?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement stm=con.prepareStatement(query);
            stm.setInt(1, id);
            stm.setString(2, name);
            stm.setInt(3, salary);
            stm.executeUpdate();
            //.println(value);
            out.println("Record Added");
            con.close();
        }


        catch(SQLException e){
            out.println("SQL Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        if(request.getParameter("submit").equals("view")){ 
            try{
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
                Statement stm=con.createStatement();
                ResultSet res=stm.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM employee");
                while(res.next()){
                    out.println(res.getString("id")+","+res.getString("name")+","+res.getString("salary"));
                }
                out.println("Records");
                con.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException e){
                out.println("SQL Exception");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(request.getParameter("submit").equals("update")){
            try{
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
            String query="UPDATE employee SET name=?,salary=? WHERE id=?";
            PreparedStatement stm=con.prepareStatement(query);
            stm.setString(1, name);
            stm.setInt(2, salary);
            stm.setInt(3, id);
            stm.executeUpdate();
            //.println(value);
            out.println("Record Updated");
            con.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException e){

            }

        }


    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // resource release
        super.destroy();
    }
}
```

Problem is when i am only perforimg the add function,it doesn't give me any error and data is added to the database but after adding view functionality,i started getting number format exception.
So someone please tell whats the problem here.
Program Stack Trace(after clicking view button):

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.gaurav.HelloServlet] in context with path [/Servlets] threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at com.gaurav.HelloServlet.doPost(HelloServlet.java:40)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your stacktrace, the exception is happening on line 40.. which on my count is:

```
int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
```

The servlet seems not to be receiving the id, so the problem is ocurring. I suggest you to run on debug mode and check which attributes are being received on the servlet.

Comment: But i am not having any problem while adding data to the database

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fetching record using column name res.getString("id"); use index position to fetch data like following.

```
 while(res.next())
{
out.println(res.getInt(1)+" "+res.getString(2)+" "+res.getString(3));
}
```